# Python post requests and read cookies in the response

Tags: python, cookies

I am writing a python program which will send a post request with a password, if the password is correct, the server will return a special cookie "BDCLND".

I did this in Postman first. You can see the url, headers, the password I used and the response cookies in the snapshots below.

[image]

[image]

The response cookie didn't have the "BDCLND" cookie because the password 'ssss' was wrong. However, the server did send a 'BAIDUID' cookie back, now, if I sent another post request with the 'BAIDUID' cookie and the correct password 'v0vb', the "BDCLND" cookie would show up in the response. Like this:
[image]

Then I wrote the python program like this:

```
import requests
import string
import re
import sys

def main():
    url = "https://pan.baidu.com/share/verify?surl=pK753kf&t=1508812575130&bdstoken=null&channel=chunlei&clienttype=0&web=1&app_id=250528&logid=MTUwODgxMjU3NTEzMTAuMzM2MTI4Njk5ODczMDUxNw=="
    headers = {
        "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Referer":"https://pan.baidu.com/share/init?surl=pK753kf"    
    }
    password={'pwd': 'v0vb'}
    response = requests.post(url=url, data=password, headers=headers)
    cookieJar = response.cookies
    for cookie in cookieJar:
        print(cookie.name)

    response = requests.post(url=url, data=password, headers=headers, cookies=cookieJar)
    cookieJar = response.cookies
    for cookie in cookieJar:
        print(cookie.name)
main()
```

When I run this, the first forloop did print up "BAIDUID", so that part is good, However, the second forloop printed nothing, it turned out the second cookiejar was just empty. I am not sure what I did wrong here. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second response has no cookies because you set the request cookies manually in the `cookies` parameter, so the server won't send a 'Set-Cookie' header.

Passing cookies across requests with the `cookies` parameter is not a good idea, use a [Session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) object instead.

```
import requests

def main():
    ses = requests.Session()
    ses.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5'
    url = "https://pan.baidu.com/share/verify?surl=pK753kf&t=1508812575130&bdstoken=null&channel=chunlei&clienttype=0&web=1&app_id=250528&logid=MTUwODgxMjU3NTEzMTAuMzM2MTI4Njk5ODczMDUxNw=="
    ref = "https://pan.baidu.com/share/init?surl=pK753kf"
    headers = {"Referer":ref}
    password={'pwd': 'v0vb'}

    response = ses.get(ref)
    cookieJar = ses.cookies
    for cookie in cookieJar:
        print(cookie.name)

    response = ses.post(url, data=password, headers=headers)
    cookieJar = ses.cookies
    for cookie in cookieJar:
        print(cookie.name)

main()
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, this time I can print out 'BAIDUID' cookie in the second response, but still no "BDCLND" cookie...

Comment: I actually noticed that the status of the second response is '404 not found' while in postman, it is 200 OK. Wonder why there's a difference..

Comment: You have to spoof User-Agent and get some cookies from the Referer, i've updated the code.

Comment: Wonderful! Now it works!! Thanks! You saved me hours!